# How can I print a variable inside a function from a different file?

Tags: python-3.x, game-development

I am making a game and I need to print a variable from a function that is in another file. I have tried making them global, but I still get the error.

Function file:

```
from Computers import YourComputer
from Computers import Computer1

def StartNetwork():

    global routerIP
    global username
    global password

    routerIP = "192.168.0.0"
    username = "admin"
    password = "password"
```

Script:

```
from Network import StartNetwork

def Terminal():
    x = 1
    while x == 1:
        cmd = input("> ")

        if cmd == "network_info":
            print(routerIP)
```

Error:

File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PythonGame\Terminal.py", line 9, in Terminal
    print(routerIP)
NameError: name 'routerIP' is not defined

Comment: You probably want to import a class, or a whole module - this just isn't how method imports work in terms of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using classes in Python

**File - x**

```
class x:
    routerIP = "192.168.0.0"
    username = "admin"
    password = "password"

def startnetwork(self):
    pass
```

**File - y**

```
from x import x
def Terminal():
    a = x()
    print(x.routerIP)


Terminal()
```

run file : y.py

output: `192.168.0.0`